Can sexual consent be required to enter a building?
First off, and this should be assumed, but IDs are checked and all people entering are of age.
Now, there are technically two questions I'm asking.
The first: is it legal in the United States for someone to require a sexual consent form in order to enter a building and will it protect the owner and anybody who performs sexual advances in the building?
The second, and this one is a worrying concept; can an employer require this at a work building, but as a separate contract than their employment contract?

Not a lawyer, but I suspect that an employer requiring their employees to consent to sexual advances would probably run afoul of sexual harassment claims pretty quick. Even brothels don't usually require their workers to consent to any particular customer - they just don't get paid for the customer's they refuse.

What do you mean by "require a sexual consent form"? It's potentially reasonable for an employer or maybe someone else (maybe someone responsible for vulnerable people?) to confirm that you are aware of the law of consent, just as they might require you to complete sexual harassment training, other health and safety training, or the sort of training that's supposed to ensure you don't do anything illegal and the company doesn't get sued (depending on the nature of the job). It's not reasonable for them to require you to consent to sexual activity.

canada
This form would be irrelevant to an analysis of consent. Consent must be subjective and contemporaneous with the impugned act. See Criminal Code, s. 265 and especially s. 273.1(1.1): "Consent must be present at the time the sexual activity in question takes place." See also R. v. J.A., 2011 SCC 28 at para 23: "Consent for this purpose is actual subjective consent in the mind of the complainant at the time of the sexual activity in question."

Thank you for your answer! I was thinking this might be the case, but wasn't sure where to look to get the answer.

Similar for Australia plus it must also be ongoing

Also the same for almost every U.S. jurisdiction (there are, or until very recently were, a handful where consent can't be withdrawn in the middle of having sex, and most U.S. jurisdiction would look to the reasonable belief of the offender based upon overt acts of the alleged victim that there was consent, rather than a purely subjective internal perspective of the alleged victim). There is no English speaking jurisdiction in the 21st century where you can make a binding consent to sex in advance that can't be withdrawn.
